# How to get linkedin profile information using identity provider and asp.net MVC 5

Tags: linkedin-api, asp.net-identity

I am developing login application using identity provider 2.0. 
I can successfully login to app using linkedin.

now I want to get more information from logged user using user using linked access token.

```
 XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
        doc1.Load("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,certifications,date-of-birth,email-address,picture-url,summary,public-profile-url,positions,skills,location)?oauth2_access_token=" + ss);
```

this download basic profile information and how to download full profile from linkedin ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at their API it is well documented. You'll need additional permissions to retrieve the full profile. [LinkedIn Profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api)